# Put output of find $PWD in a column

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to put the output of `find $PWD` (all the files and directories in the current directory and subdirectories) in one column... right now its printing out all as one row.
An example:

```
/Users/blah /Users/blah/blah /Users/blah/blah/blah.txt
```

I need it to be

```
/Users/blah
/Users/blah/blah
/Users/blah/blah/blah.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: try @brotherofken's answer.. in my computer `find $PWD` already gives "per-line" output, though..

Comment: Why are you doing `find $PWD` rather than just `find` (directory argument is optional and should = `$PWD` if none is entered). Couple of things would help figure out why this is happening for you `find --version` and `type find` (e.g. `-print0` option hardset)

Comment: We need more context. It's not just a coincidence that no one else is seeing this behavior; `find` shouldn't behave as you're describing, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that you're capturing this data in a variable or otherwise passing it through echo:

```
var=$(find $PWD)
echo $var
--or--
echo $(find $PWD)
```

This causes the effect you see because you neglected quoting. You should always double quote almost all variables and command substitutions:

```
var=$(find "$PWD")
echo "$var"
--or--
echo "$(find "$PWD")"
```

This will print the data like it was captured, with line feeds instead of spaces.

Comment: +1 for making an intelligent guess regarding the actual problem, rather than suggesting a fix for a problem that, as per the POSIX spec, shouldn't exist (and therefore is very unlikely to actually exist on OP's system).

Answer (score 1):

On my computer `find $PWD` gives one file per line too, as Yohanes Khosiawan said.

But try to force it with

```
find $PWD -printf "%p\n"
```

Extract from `man find`:

> ```
>    -printf format
>       print format on the standard output, interpreting '\'  escapes  and  '%'  directives.   Field
>       widths  and  precisions can be specified as with the 'printf' C function.
> ```

Same similar thins using `ls`

```
ls -1
```

Extract from help:

> ```
> -1 -- (The numeric digit "one")
>       Force output to be one entry per line. 
>       This is the default when output is not to a terminal.
> ```